# Overlapping String-Blocks

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, matrix

### Challenge:

Given a list of multi-line strings, overlap them (in the top-left) and output the result.

**Example:**

Input: `["aaaa\naaaa\naaaa\naaaa","bb\nbb\nbb","c"]`
Output:

```
cbaa
bbaa
bbaa
aaaa
```

### Challenge rules:

- Input-format is flexible. You are allowed to get the input as a 2D list of lines (i.e. `[["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"],["bb","bb","bb"],["c"]]`) or 3D list of characters (i.e. `[[["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"]],[["b","b"],["b","b"],["b","b"]],[["c"]]]`). You are allowed to take all the inputs one by one through STDIN. Etc.
- Output format is strict. You can choose to print or return the multi-line string. (If your language doesn't have any strings, outputting as a 2D list of characters is allowed as alternative. But only if your language doesn't have strings at all.)
- The order of the input-list is of course important (but you are allowed to take the input in reverse if you choose to).
- Inputs will only contain printable ASCII in the unicode range \$[33,126]\$ (`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ``).
- Inputs will only be rectangles (so no weird shapes). The output aren't necessary rectangles, though.
- Trailing spaces and a single trailing newline is allowed. Leading spaces and/or newlines not.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

Input: `["aaaa\naaaa\naaaa\naaaa","bb\nbb\nbb","c"]`
Output:

```
cbaa
bbaa
bbaa
aaaa
```

Input: `["12345\n54321","00\n00\n00\n00","001\n011\n012"]`
Output:

```
00145
01121
012
00
```

Input: `["sm\noo\nmr\nee\nt!\nh_\ni_\nn_\ng_","!@#$%^\n&*()_+\nqwerty\nuiopas","this\nis_a\ntest"]`
Output:

```
this%^
is_a_+
testty
uiopas
t!
h_
i_
n_
g_
```

Comment: Are trailing newlines allowed? Or more specifically, is an arbitrary amount of trailing newlines allowed?

Comment: @JAD Yeah sure, why not. As long as the rest is output without any leading spaces/newlines. Trailing newlines/spaces aren't really important, so can optionally be added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
a/Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9RP/L/4fZHTWuyHjXM4eL6/z@aSwEIoqOVEoFASQcbFasTrZSUBOTBCJBAslJsrA5Mr6GRsYkpUM7UxNjIECxtYADkohAQUUMQxxBCGiEbUZwLFMvPBxK5RUAiNRVIlCgCiYx4IJEJIvJARHo82CRFB2UV1TggX01LQzNeG8goLE8tKqkEMkoz8wsSi8GqSjIyi0G6i@NBnilJLS4BWskVCwA)

Hadn't used Jelly in a while but I thought the challenge in the comments was beatable. Very directly uses logical and (`a`) to perform the stacking operation between each element of the input (`/`). `Y` is used to print in the required format.

Comment: Ah nice! I'm pretty bad with Jelly tbh. My prepared solution was [`ḷ""/Y`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju1KSvqR////j45WKsnILFbSUcosjk8EUiWpxSVKsTrRSooOyiqqcUARNS0NzXhtIKOwPLWopBLIKM3ML0gsBqsqzgXy8/OBRG4RkEhNBRmhCCQy4kFmgog8EJEerxQbCwA) with a reversed input-list. Didn't even knew about `a`..

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 24 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Grimy*

Assumes that the returned string is printed on a terminal that supports [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Contains the unprintable character <kbd>ESC</kbd>, which is escaped (no pun intended) as `\x1B` below.

```javascript
a=>`\x1B[2J\x1B[H`+a.join`\x1B[H`
```

This doesn't work on TIO, but you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzLDoIwEEU/hBX1kSLKwj3GpfEXGG0bLFACM9ipGr@@1sVJ7uLcM5q34da7JRyQHjZ2dTT1SWfN8Zo1F12aaiSH@r9jS8g02WqiXnayETwDEgHOHtBawJADDgrQJTDRK7EX@Xm13twBtztZqBLw@bE@fAFfjhbDSQiD4/RhZVLBchC3oog/) to see the raw output instead.

#### How?

The [CSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) used are:

- ED (Erase in Display):

  <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

  where \$2\$ means *"clear entire screen"*
- CUP (Cursor Position):

  <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

  which means *"moves the cursor to row \$n\$, column \$m\$"* where both \$n\$ and \$m\$ are omitted and implicitly set to \$1\$ (top-left corner of the screen).

#### Example output

[image: output]

Comment: Assuming an ECMA-48 compliant terminal, you can omit both `;`. Also, I think this should be "JavaScript + terminal" or something similar that doesn't compete with pure JavaScript.

Comment: @Grimy Thanks! (For anyone interested, [here is the ECMA-48 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) -- but I didn't find where it's mentioned that the semicolon can be omitted -- if it's mentioned at all.)

Comment: 5.4.2.h is somewhat confusingly worded, but the interesting bit is: `if the last parameter sub-string(s) is empty, the separator preceding it may be omitted`. Since there are only two sub-strings, the separator preceding the last substring is the only one, and it can be omitted.

Comment: I don't know ANSI, but is the first `\x1B[H`+ necessary? Isn't it starting at the top-left by default, and you only need to reset it after each input (which is what join does)? Or does it initially start somewhere else by default, and you have to explicitly let it start at that cursor position for it to successfully reset to that position in the join?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen By default it starts wherever the cursor is, typically at the start of a new line after the current prompt + command. Just try on TIO and copy-paste the output to a terminal to see what I mean.

Comment: @Grimy Ah ok. I indeed saw the CUP mentioned, but didn't knew it was the mouse cursor. Thought it might have been the typing cursor. I don't know the meta, but I guess we can't assume the mouse cursor is at the top-left, can we? ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I do mean the typing cursor, not the mouse cursor. Running a command in a terminal typically requires typing it, which leaves the typing cursor not at the top left.

Comment: Isn't meta-consensus that functions should be reusable? Since the ANSI escape sequence sets the cursor to the top left corner, future calls to the function will overlay the new output on top of old outputs, producing invalid output

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Chances are that the terminal is not fully cleared on the first call either, so this is not really a problem of reusability, but rather a problem of output readability. I honestly don't know which rule(s) should be applied here. Also, I was half-tempted to omit the `print()` in the function entirely and just return the string -- but I don't know if that would be allowed.

Comment: @Arnauld Since you probably will always have something else on the terminal when executing this function, I guess the initial reset is required after all. As for ommitting print, I guess ``f=a=>print(`\x1B[H`+a.join`\x1B[H`)`` with `f(input_here)` would produce the same output as `print(f(input_here))`? So I don't see why you wouldn't be allowed to omit the `print` and simply return a string.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you. I've updated the answer accordingly. (The screen is now cleared.)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>120</s>, <s>111</s> <s>110</s> 107 bytes

```r
function(x,`!`=ncol,M=array('',Reduce(pmax,Map(dim,x)))){for(m in x)M[1:!t(m),1:!m]=m
write(t(M),1,!M,,'')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBbtswDL3rK2hnm6VVG@q0vRQzsFsv82XXKEsVRW4EWJQnKavbIt@e0t7WYcMuFUCKEh4fHyXG0wL2th9shO6AJruAYAL@sDE7vIO8dwm6EL3OcA2Gl/Xy4vJK4dXlxbIuZXl@rvCPzRc1RfXslqVgC8gBNPQuZQgdEE904xSZvY7aZBsTu2l@l@aP4okBfGkmPBcUOvj0AWoKSATX4BBSjmnoXeaPslJYiTmDclYrt15P6F34aHTf87h1uJMvcC0rAs/YmdTB2Ux8nAqyI2Njc8OpQ01L4b@eWttuFf40OpiSuLrm9KJ8lLfFbYMm9LJtdIz6gVeV/Gp3B2P54PUoWz3wnfNyFLSepn781M8o2lV9XWTuhaTdrxvP7qPLlmfe0pUsWjlJP546/kqBghmd@fxK7FfyK//vfxTJKwxBoY8KrVWYC4X7jUJHhmR3G@IpPi/evP2m8N17LjZnCr/f00Q9KDy4MOhEgGmyKCdtSH@2Kf9d6/QM)

A function accepting a list of matrix of characters (3D input is accepted).

(as you can notice from the byte count, this is not very easy to do in R...)

- -9 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe
- -4 bytes thanks to @RobinRyder

Comment: I was really expecting a 200+ byte solution! I'll be giving this a nice bounty whenever this question becomes bounty eligibile

Comment: @Giuseppe: still much longer than other languages ... :(

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVLBTuMwEL37K4Z0l9iLQaTApSLS3rjQy17rbuW6DrVIxlnbhQDqt5dxWFjtai9YGut58ubNG8fhMIGtbXsboNmhSc4jGI8PNiSHd5C2LkLjQ6cTzMDwoppeXF4pvLq8mFaFLM7PFf6JMVERqsZtWgg2geRBQ@tiAt8A6QQ3ZGS2OmiTbIjspn5vzZ/FCwO4rTOfC4IOrk@hIkAmuAaHEFOIfesSf5alwlKMFVSzWLjlMrM3/szotuVh7XAjP@halkQeuaOog5NReJ8bsj1jQ33DaUJNS@G/O422Xit8CzqYgrSa@vDhfJDzWoegn3hZyh92szOW952mtO75xnVyELRe8hhdHmMQ80U14/fXp/SRd0LIana/mC6Xdcceg0uWJz6npETj24yy/f2h4Z80KZjRiY83xX4Xf/If/k8idgq9V9gFhdYqTEcKtyuFjgIp7lakc/R98uXrT4XH37hYnSj89Uiv6knhzvleRyLk10U1cUX@k43p716HVw) using `array` instead of `matrix`!

Comment: @Giuseppe: neat !

Comment: [110](https://tio.run/##lVLBTuMwEL37K4aUJfbiRaS0F7SRuHGhl73WpXJdh1pKxlnbpQHUb@9OAhTtai@1NNbz6M2bN7bDYQQbW7c2QLVFk5xHMB6fbUgOnyBtXITKh0YnuAXDs2J8M5kqnE5uxkUms@trhV8xJApCxbCNM8FGkDxoqF1M4CsgneC6HpmNDtokGyK7Lz9b81fxxgAeyp7PBUEHP39AQYBMcA0OIaYQ29ol/ipzhbkYKqhmPneLRc9e@yuj65qHlcO1PNK1zIk8cAdRB5eD8L5vyPaMdeU9pwk1LYX/7jTaaqXwPehgMtKqysPReSdnpQ5Bv/A8l7/semssbxtNad3ytWtkJ2i99WM0/RidmM2LWwx@xxshCRlfE1qUDdsFlyxPfEZ5OeQJ9e73h4qf6FEwoxMfLop9FJ/4hP@TiI1C7xU2QaG1CtOZws1SoaNAiqcl6Zzdjc6/PSq8@M7F8lLh7x19qheFW@dbHYnQfy6qiUvyn2xMf/c6/AE "R – Try It Online") by switching back to good old `ncol` and `nrow`.

Comment: @RobinRyder: thanks ! I started using dim everywhere in order to replace it with some alias, but I ended up with more bytes :D

Comment: [107](https://tio.run/##lVLBbtswDL3rK2hnm6VVG@q0vRQzsFsv82XXKEsVRW4EWJQnKavbIt@e0t7WYcMuFUCKEh4fHyXG0wL2th9shO6AJruAYAL@sDE7vIO8dwm6EL3OcA2Gl/Xy4vJK4dXlxbIuZXl@rvCPzRc1RfXslqVgC8gBNPQuZQgdEE904xSZvY7aZBsTu2l@l@aP4okBfGkmPBcUOvj0AWoKSATX4BBSjmnoXeaPslJYiTmDclYrt15P6F34aHTf87h1uJMvcC0rAs/YmdTB2Ux8nAqyI2Njc8OpQ01L4b@eWttuFf40OpiSuLrm9KJ8lLfFbYMm9LJtdIz6gVeV/Gp3B2P54PUoWz3wnfNyFLSepn781M8o2lV9XWTuhaTdrxvP7qPLlmfe0pUsWjlJP546/kqBghmd@fxK7FfyK//vfxTJKwxBoY8KrVWYC4X7jUJHhmR3G@IpPi/evP2m8N17LjZnCr/f00Q9KDy4MOhEgGmyKCdtSH@2Kf9d6/QM "") with an alias for `ncol` (you can transpose to get `nrow`).

Comment: [107](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186414/59530), different solution, same bytecount. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 88 bytes

```python
n,f=None,filter
for l in map(n,*input()):print''.join(f(n,x)[-1]for x in map(n,*f(n,l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NbsMgEIX3nILQH4xLq2Anm0qReoJeANHKcXFNZAPBRHVO7zJYlVqpLD5m3rw346@xd7ZaWvehD4SQxfLu8Oqs5p0Zog6ocwEP2Fg8Nr6wvDTWX2LB2LMPxkZKn07O2KJLo5nJR6HAP//yw2RgjC3Zj9IJhPSsWwwXy3qRkoiq3u0JJ/tdXQmiuCTbbWr/YFUFNGJlRZRCKd2kl4R/Psgcj6n7AQjtGqPTSDmmzgHHANQaGDfAHgNNps38xFRxLOnm5eb27g2U@7Jg7w9Qnb90iFeoLsb5ZlqdsTdT3jLhJm/WU6RKfQM)

---

#### Explanation (with example):

Takes a 2D list as input.

```python
Input: [["12345","54321"],["00","00","00","00"],["001","011","012"]]
```

First the input list is zipped, to get the rows of each input rectangle (`map(None,l)` is the same a zip longest):

```python
map(n,*input())   gives:

('12345', '00', '001')
('54321', '00', '011')
(None, '00', '012')
(None, '00', None)
```

Each of these rows are then filtered to removed `None`s, and zipped again:

```python
map(None,*filter(None,l))

filter(None,l) for each l gives:

('12345', '00', '001')
('54321', '00', '011')
('00', '012')
('00',)

map*... gives:

[('1', '0', '0'), ('2', '0', '0'), ('3', None, '1'), ('4', None, None), ('5', None, None)]
[('5', '0', '0'), ('4', '0', '1'), ('3', None, '1'), ('2', None, None), ('1', None, None)]
[('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), (None, '2')]
['0', '0']
```

Which is a list of characters for each position of the desired result. These lists are filtered again, and the last one is taken:

```python
filter(None,x)   gives:

[('1', '0', '0'), ('2', '0', '0'), ('3', '1'), ('4',), ('5',)]
[('5', '0', '0'), ('4', '0', '1'), ('3', '1'), ('2',), ('1',)]
[('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('2',)]
['0', '0']

and with [-1]:

['0', '0', '1', '4', '5']
['0', '1', '1', '2', '1']
['0', '1', '2']
['0', '0']
```

Lastly the resulting lists are joined and printed:

```python
print''.join(..)

00145
01121
012
00
```

Comment: RE "Returns a list of strings", the rules state "Output format is strict. You can choose to print or return the multi-line string. 2D or 3D lists as outputs aren't allowed.". The 88 byte full program seems fine though

Comment: @JonathanAllan, welp, I misread the strict output (or forgot? :p)

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>107</s> 97 bytes

```
function(x)for(i in 1:max(lengths(x))){for(m in x)if(i<=length(m))cat(m[i],'\r',sep='');cat('
')}
```

Doesn't appear to work on TIO, which might be related to the use of the `\r` carriage return character. It does work on my local installation of R.

Takes input as a list containing a vector of rows:

```
x <- list(c("aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"),c("bb","bb","bb"),c("c"))
```

Loops over the rows of each rectangle, printing a carriage return after each, restarting the line.

If we stretch the rules a little, we can do away with checking the length of the input and just loop infinitely, printing a huge amount of newlines:

## R, 85 bytes

```
function(x)for(i in 1:8e8){for(m in x)if(i<=length(m))cat(m[i],'\r',sep='');cat('
')}
```

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcoxDgIhEAXQ3lPQzfyELWyVPYKNrVoQBJ0EWIJsQmI8O4b25dURlFlG2LNrsmXuCFtlUZLV8XT1z915Lsl2fbGFo1miz6/21h3Ad840Z4cEFrNGToCzjdNNHprulfTHl5UI56l0IPzG@AM) Nice to see you doing a golf here and there!

Comment: Possibly [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc2xCgIxDAbg3acoXZJAHVz17knUoVcuGrj2pO1BQXz22ipuZkj4/29IrKyGfeUtuCxrwEK8RhQlQR2O3hZc5nDL99SA6NnNdyskjDKMX0VP5GxGf5argUsEk@bHCECn3sIO6FUZF0kZHWrbRpt/h0zjaWrxtz6N0@13fQM); unclear if this actually works since I'm only testing in TIO

Comment: @Giuseppe Hi! Your suggestion works for me. If we are allowed to print trailing newlines, it's also possible to just use an arbitrarily big for loop instead, but I guess that's pushing the limits of the challenge.

Comment: @JAD: great idea using `\r`, and welcome back! Just a note, I think this works only in interactive R sessions (when `interactive()` returns true)

Comment: @digEmAll It works on my machine using `rscript` from commandline. I suspect it's a Windows/Linux thing, since Windows uses `\r\n` for newlines and Linux `\n`.

Comment: @JAD: oh, I would have bet on the interactive thing... but then it's probably that

Comment: @digEmAll it might also depend on the console it's being ran in. CMD and powershell deal with the `\r` as intended. It might be that other environments (like TIO) interpret it as a newline. May I ask what you are running it in?

Comment: @digEmAll: rstudio on windows

Comment: @digEmAll well..... that's odd. It works for me there :O

Comment: @JAD: yes, it works for me too... I was just trying to understand why it does not work on TIO ;)

Comment: @digEmAll ah, right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94569/discussion-between-digemall-and-jad).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking list of 2D character arrays as argument. Prints.

```apl
(⊃{⍺@(⍳⍴⍺)⊢⍵}/)⌽,∘⊂1⌷↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT//vmfeobcKjvqluviGHVjzqmAFkegX7@6nHxOSpA9lBQEaR@n@NR13N1Y96dzloPOrd/Kh3C5Cp@ahr0aPerbX6mo969uqAdHY1GT7q2f6obeL/NJCZvX1A/Z7@QJ2H1hsDRYG84CBnIBni4Rn8P03BM089WikRCGLy0EklHaWkpJg8CAZykpVi1bl0dXW5oLoMjYxNTGPyTE2MjQyB0gYGMXkIDBYwBLIMwYQRmt7i3Ji8/PyYvNyimLzU1Ji8EsWYvIz4mLxMIM4D4vR4oAGKDsoqqnExeWpaGprx2jF5heWpRSWVMXmlmfkFicVABSUZmcVAPcXxQBeXpBaXAC0BAA)

This works by creating a canvas, then appending that to the list of blocks, and reducing (folding) with a function that places blocks in the corner.

`↑` mix the 2D block to create an orthogonal 3D block, padding them with spaces as needed

`1⌷` take the first layer

`⊂` enclose that
 `∘` then
`⌽,` prepend the reversed list of blocks

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`{`…`}/` reduce using the following anonymous lambda:

`⊢⍵` with the right argument as canvas…

`⍺@(`…`)` amend with the elements of the left argument, placed **at** the following indices:

`⍴⍺` the shape of the left argument

`⍳` the **ɩ**ndices of an array of that shape

`⊃` disclose (because the reduction enclosed to reduce rank)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 66 bytes

```
unlines.foldl((const?)?)[]
(g?(a:b))(c:d)=g a c:(g?b)d;(_?a)b=a++b
```

Input is taken as a list of list of strings in reverse order, e.g. for the first test case: `[["c"],["bb","bb","bb"],["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"]]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7bTsMwDIbv9xRZOSihY1q77aaoKg8AV1zWJUrT9CBStzQpiJenWJ0EEpY@y/7tX3ar3JuxdqlTWGa0HRq3rwdbWc71gM5nIhN5seFNxlVSCsF1Uom0YYrphMRSVA9cZkqUqQrDculVhyxlvRqfJePj7F/89IRsz2qCVLZeoHoyH2ZyRrB8wxjLA0UB@D8Hu6AsAS9Qo4Nid9mP4uPpDHg@HeOIBocD4B@rEFEVrSn@dbkecBgA@wnQGEC/BWwlYEcg0Uiybh@vrm9eAW/vuJAh4PunmfwX4NwNo3K04NvOkcdJ@tIb54OiWL51bVXjlns9jj8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Port of [TFeld's python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186373/47066)
2 bytes saved thanks to *Grimy*

```
ζεðKζðδK€θJ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9LDoIwEIavgvURH3AH13KEBk1NGiERKhZjcOl5XLBQ4p59D@FFan9GSTdfvsnMtP8oLfaZtNa05tU1sWm7xjzjz/1h3pvQWs450ywMWM6SMOBMwRV5Dj@TS7gkr@Aj8hS@I888Lzw//BwFd4uuWgNjYAJMgS1Nz@BLYA4saNlhRf0SfqU4fT6HPlFN/Qs8ozMcToAA9D9BP50OY9pLr4ffhHerHFqVeyOxUVSo6Chu9Rc)

**Explanation**

```
ζ             # transpose input with space as filler
 ε            # apply to each
  ðK          # remove spaces
    ζ         # transpose with space as filler
     ðδK      # deep remove spaces
        €θ    # get the tail of each
          J   # join each
           ,  # print
```

**Alternative 14 byte version**

```
õζεÅ»DŠg.$J}θ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NZz285tPdx6aLfL0QXpeipeted26Pz/Hx2tVJyrpKOUnw8kcouARGoqkChRBBIZCkAiE0TkgYh0BaVYHYVoJUUHZRXVOKCAmpaGZrw2kFFYnlpUUglklGbmFyQWQ5SVZGQWg/QXKySCDEwtLlGKjf2vq5uXr5uTWFUJAA)

**Explanation**

```
õζ              # zip with empty string as filler
  ε             # apply to each
   Å»      }    # cumulative reduce by
     D          # duplicate second input
      Š         # move down twice on stack
       g.$      # remove len(other_copy) elements from the other input
          J     # join with other copy
            θ,  # print the last element
```

Comment: Oh, need to remember that `--no-lazy` is the fix to still use a map/filter with print for the implicit `y`, to save a byte in comparison to `vy...,` :) I knew that worked in the legacy version, but in the new version it would also output the `[...]`. Didn't knew that was due to the lack of `--no-lazy`. ;) As for the answer itself, very nice! I knew a cumulative reduce was necessary, but couldn't really work it out when I tried it myself. You make it look so easy..

Comment: I had it mentioned in the rules, but forgot to apply it to the test cases.., but spaces won't be in the input. So you can probably save some bytes there since the zip-filler is a space by default. (Not sure if it saves anything in your first answer, but in the port it might.)

Comment: `õζεõK` can be `ζεðK`, `õζõδK` can be `ζðδK`.

Comment: @Grimy: Oh yeah, spaces can no longer be in the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｈ１１╋╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjI4JXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXUyNTRC,i=JTVCJTIyJTIxJTIxJTIxJTVDJTVDJTIyJTJDJTIyYWFhLyU1Q25hYWFhJTVDbmFhYWElNUNuYWFhYSUyMiUyQyUyMmJiJTVDbmJiJTVDbmJiJTIyJTJDJTIyYyUyMiU1RA__,v=8)

If overlapping `/`+`\` → `X`, `-` + `|` → `+`, etc. would be fine, [2 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjI4JXVGRjRF,i=JTVCJTIyJTIxJTIxJTIxJTVDJTVDJTIyJTJDJTIyYWFhLyU1Q25hYWFhJTVDbmFhYWElNUNuYWFhYSUyMiUyQyUyMmJiJTVDbmJiJTVDbmJiJTIyJTJDJTIyYyUyMiU1RA__,v=8) would work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

```python
for t in map(None,*input()):
 r=''
 for s in t:
	if s:r=s+r[len(s):]
 print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxNbsMgEIXX5RQT@oOdsAhOskGKlBP0AohWTkRqpBgoECU5vctgdVGps/hm3tObFx558K6bboO9GBDS3M2JUjqdfYQM1sHYh@bdO8OX1oVrbtpWEoh7xghgJmEmS/Jkz5Bk3KdVVBfjmtRKTSBE6zLEqW6CvUpR0W22O8rpbrvpBNVc0fW6yD@YXYFCzOyo1qR892WK8c/Cn@OxqF@gcZrfWBoZB@Y9coxIY5B5gRwAaStd5RcwzUGxxeH55fUDnbdl036u8Pq@mZgfeF2tD32ak3mwqbYk6GuzSZlp/QM)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell 6](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), console only, 20 bytes

based on Arnauld's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186374/80745).
This work with console only and doesn't work on TIO.

```powershell
cls
$args-join"`e[H"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9PzmnmEslsSi9WDcrPzNPKSE12kPpfy0XlxpQXikRCBLy0EklBaWkpIQ8CAZykpX@AwA)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 103 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$l=$_-split'
';$r=&{$r+($l|%{''})|%{($x=$l[$j++])+($_-replace"^.{0,$("$x"|% Le*)}")}|?{$_}}}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJtbqMwEP3PKRxnCFBIFWjyaxVtDrA3WDU2od6ElTNQ7GgTEc6eDtAPqKruSGPzZt48D/aUxT9VmYPS@gZ/2JrVN0irvbm6Neg1iLkpdW49x/sB1XpWQxX6oCnpeU1Amw/nNejf8DcMHwNKiXmlSp1mim/v60UEPoczv7rsl7oLGh401581iKZpHKhujeNsfIeRRf3W2sbnKZnEzyuP@G4nsXcCGQ@i9yov26WpN8C7/@BW0etg4HzRQpw8LFcSV8uHJKazFguJH94FYvqKuyUZNUKZ5Wp4ErGSeBxIRnDxTR/mKLEoJB4riUpJtBOJByExJ0fyvaBmJpspuFuJszs/EKHEZ3pQe5F4yosyNUSwh9xQjRF0lVYZO2q4TbrbYUctUYTDSFtkL8NIrz3iTIboIEaKI4QjtBdv/x@wK3NZ3SHQOSoTgTqXKrPqiQYTRJ@plDlpS4EZzeum47EpozFNrc1x35H4K4vP1TN/F@FdbvqmMGUnzIrjUaFl7S2wVovZgj3lrdqF9TzjNM7tBQ)

Unrolled:

```powershell
$args|%{
    $l=$_-split"`n"
    $r=&{                           # run this scriptblock in a new scope
        $r+($l|%{''})|%{
            $x=$l[$j++]             # a new line or $null
            $w="$x"|% Length
            $y=$_-replace"^.{0,$w}" # remove first chars from the current line
            $x+$y                   # output the new line plus tail of the overlapped line
        }|?{$_}                     # filter out not empty lines only
    }                               # close the scope and remove all variables created in the scope
}
$r
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 68 + 23 = 91 bytes

```cs
n=>{C.Clear();n.ForEach(k=>{C.SetCursorPosition(0,0);C.Write(k);});}
```

23 bytes is for the import, `using C=System.Console;`

Does not work in TIO, since it isn't a console.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5Na8MwDD0nv8Lk5EBnencTGKYbOwwKPezQ9uB4ambqyCA5GyPkt2deu@0wIQn00PtwfOciwTKyx16YZv/JCQZlInIMoEsXLLPYUezJDmIqOdnknfh5u3fJR9z8kUKAK8LqERDIO/W0xXEAsl2ADSfKJm17bhZs2skoE8CSrDWqh0hb697k5YrvIZmRONIusv/Wk@vVutZGvZBPIC@1nnMv@jfNe/Sv4tl6lDeLw0lY6rnOeYviLBE@DqepsrmO@H9Xq6rrjnibfLgqa5fFXM7LFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

Input is a list of lines. Builds a list of lines and does overwriting as it goes through the inputs, then joins them with a newline (represented by the variable `$/`) at the end to match the strict output.

```ruby
->i,*r{i.map{|e|j=-1;e.map{|l|r[j+=1]||='';r[j][0,l.size]=l}};r*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRCoMgAEXf/YqQoNXKqdVTcz@SPjRmYFiI1cOWfrtrGyO45@FeONeu92foGQ/FTeWZ3RQaO7M56QZWkEb@mna2Hc6MCOdYkjR7ES3ONZrVSwqmvW9sFl98UJNZl4hF8RVZ2T3QbLRaTpBPfILp/1geM0w92I056tuvKgKhZVWDuiopAQDjIzsEYPKBvgE)

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC, MinGW) 138 bytes

Assumes that CR puts the cursor at the start of the current line.

```
d,i,l;f(S,n,p,t)char**S,*p,*t;{for(d=i=0;i<n;d+=l)p=strchr(t=S[i],10),printf("\n%.*s\r"+!!i,l=p?p-t:strlen(t),t),S[i++]+=l+!!p;d&&f(S,n);}
```

Tested with:

```
int main()
{
    char *test1[] = {"aaaa\naaaa\naaaa\naaaa","bb\nbb\nbb","c"};
    char *test2[] = {"12345\n54321","00\n00\n00\n00","001\n011\n012"};
    char *test3[] = {"sm\noo\nmr\nee\nt!\nh_\ni_\nn_\ng_","!@#$%^\n&*()_+\nqwerty\nuiopas","this\nis_a\ntest"};
    
    f(test1, 3);
    f(test2, 3);
    f(test3, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```matlab
function y=f(x)
for k=1:size(x)
y(1:(t=size(x{k})),1:t(2))=x{k};end
```

Function that takes a vertical cell array of char matrices, and returns a char matrix.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP0@h0jZNo0KTKy2/SCHb1tCqOLMqFcSv1DC00iixhXCrs2s1NXUMrUo0jDQ1bUFc69S8lP9AzJWSWVygkaZRHa2eCATq1ihUrLVCtHpSEpALJMCcZPVYoFH/AQ) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##fZBLbsIwEIb3nMKoD9ttF9iBTSJLvQeiVghOsRAxxANtijh7Os5QVdlgyZ/nn6c8oYLy7Pq@PjUV@NCwztTiW07q0LKdUXn0Py7pTqhcgCF52V2lfFM5CC2lSbJwzabHOwEXwSpm2GXJSzy8GD2rgi35eo0SMYiKr64FlWkqUzqbLzBjMc@0oqTZDPUIN7dKShH1f6eMOsU9BkJA7FuEcwiYIrYW4ROahE9L/abvD49PH@h4fhHSvqJx/HItdGicfDiUkdJg62Oqjzb9Kw0cJm98PIha0AZwP2xwcMb/zFtM34llo1j/Cw).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 bytes

Takes input as an array of multi-line strings, outputs a single multi-line string.

```
ú y_¸¬Ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=%2biB5X7iszA&input=WyJzbQpvbwptcgplZQp0IQpoXwppXwpuXwpnXyIsIiFAIyQlXgomKigpXysKcXdlcnR5CnVpb3BhcyIsInRoaXMKaXNfYQp0ZXN0Il0)

```
ú y_¸¬Ì     :Implicit input of array
ú           :Right pad each line of each element with spaces to the length of the longest
  y         :Transpose
   _        :Map
    ¸       :  Split on spaces
     ¬      :  Join
      Ì     :  Last character
            :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Javascript (browser)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), <s>216</s> <s>208</s>  204 bytes

My attempt at this. I'm not happy about the size, and there must certainly be more for improvement, but I'm not that experienced at golfing.

```
var n='\n',x=s=>s.split``.reverse().join``,i,j,f=a=>a.map(s=>s.split(n).map(y=>x(y))).reduce((a,b)=>{for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){j=a[i];if(!j)j=b[i];a[i]=b[i].padStart(j.length,j)}return a}).map(s=>x(s)).join(n)
```

Anyways, what it does is first split all the strings, then reverse all the strings, then whilst looping in a reduce operation [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) all the strings together. Then reverse all the strings again and then join them back with newlines.

Special thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for reminding me that the last part in a for loop happens at the end and a total byte savings of 8 bytes.

```js
var n='\n',x=s=>s.split``.reverse().join``,i,j,f=a=>a.map(s=>s.split(n).map(y=>x(y))).reduce((a,b)=>{for(i=0;i<b.length;a[i]=b[i++].padStart(j.length,j))if(!(j=a[i]))j=b[i];return a}).map(s=>x(s)).join(n)

console.log(f(["aaaa\naaaa\naaaa\naaaa","bb\nbb\nbb","c"]));
console.log(f(["12345\n54321","00\n00\n00\n00","001\n011\n012"]));
console.log(f(["sm\noo\nmr\nee\nt!\nh_\ni_\nn_\ng_","!@#$%^\n&*()_+\nqwerty\nuiopas","this\nis_a\ntest"]));
```

Comment: Both `('')` can be two ` to save four bytes :)

Comment: Also, you can replace the `for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){j=a[i];if(!j)j=b[i];a[i]=b[i].padStart(j.length,j)}` with `for(i=0;i<b.length;a[i]=b[i++].padStart(j.length,j))if(!(j=a[i]))j=b[i];`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen In your modification j doesn't get assigned. And it will fail because the if needs to happen before padStart, otherwise you get a[i](j in this case) is undefined and cannot get property length of undefined. Thanks for the four bytes saved. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: The `j` is first assigned with `(j=a[i])`, then the if-statement is done with `if(!...)j=b[i];` (where `...` is the `(j=a[i])`, so the updated value of `j`), and then the `;a[i]=b[i++].padStart(j.length,j))` is done at the end of the for-loop iteration.. Not sure where the problem is, and it seems to work?

Comment: ooohhh.... * big eyes * that unlocked something

Comment: Btw, if you haven't seen them yet, [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) and [tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/52210) might both be interesting to read through. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```c
f(char**s){for(;*s;printf("\e[s%s\e[u",*s++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/RCsIwDHzfV4SJ0HZT8bnij6gPtctmcWtHU6cy/Pba@iAIJiHkyOXI6VWndVwYq/tbg7Cj0Bi3vuxhI2BAj/0TggOPg5sQ7spbYzsCsSkmZ5pMUj25/5TYMn1RXgjic@s8k4Lk6I0NLSuPeKAlpX4ra0FVxbl8xbSCQRnL8qB8p2vIAiDSPB1OHOYCoGUZVVsuE/jK2f9Zcvkxoq5IQKPSCOkTsPgI6dYNY8hWXjGqFMVvi@dz8amo3w)

-4 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

Uses the CSI sequences for save/restore cursor position. Just iterates over the passed string array (in the same format as `argv`) and prints `<save position>string<restore position>` for each.

This does leave the cursor at the top left, so when running at the terminal it is important to leave enough newlines afterwards so that the prompt doesn't clobber the input.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL query, <s>297</s> 295 bytes

Using ¶ as separator and a table variable as input.

```sql
DECLARE @ table(a varchar(max),k int identity(1,1))
INSERT @ values('aaaa¶aaaa¶aaaa¶aaaa'),('bb¶bv¶bb'),('c');

WITH c as(SELECT k,row_number()over(partition
by k order by k)s,value v FROM @ CROSS APPLY
string_split(a,'¶')s),m(i,l,e)as(SELECT*FROM c
WHERE k=1UNION ALL
SELECT k,s,STUFF(e,1,len(v),v)FROM m
JOIN c ON-~i=k and s=l)SELECT
top 1with ties e FROM m
ORDER BY rank()over(partition by l order by-i)
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1061453/overlapping-string-blocks)**

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (browser), <s>129</s> 124 bytes

My first attempt at code golfing. I read the links given in the rules (loopholes, standard rules...), so I hope I did anything wrong!

---

I kept the inputs as they are in the first post (flat array form).

```
_=o=>{o=o.map(i=>i.split`\n`),r=o.shift();for(a of o)for(l in a)b=a[l],r[l]=r[l]?b+r[l].slice(b.length):b;return r.join`\n`}
```

Thanks to **[Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)** for saving 5 bytes.

---

**Tests:**

```js
_=o=>{o=o.map(i=>i.split`\n`),r=o.shift();for(a of o)for(l in a)b=a[l],r[l]=r[l]?b+r[l].slice(b.length):b;return r.join`\n`}

console.log(_(["aaaa\naaaa\naaaa\naaaa","bb\nbb\nbb","c"]));
console.log(_(["12345\n54321","00\n00\n00\n00","001\n011\n012"]));
console.log(_(["sm\noo\nmr\nee\nt!\nh_\ni_\nn_\ng_","!@#$%^\n&*()_+\nqwerty\nuiopas","this\nis_a\ntest"]));
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer, +1 from me. Some small things to golf: `for(a of o){for(l in a){b=a[l],r[l]=(r[l])?b+r[l].slice(b.length):b}}` can be `for(a of o)for(l in a)b=a[l],r[l]=r[l]?b+r[l].slice(b.length):b;` :)

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Thanks, I updated my post! I read these two guides before posting, they were both useful. But I possibly miss some tricks that could improve even more my attempt!

Comment: One other thing from my first comment you missed are the parenthesis around the `=(r[l])?` which can be removed to `=r[l]?` :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Oops, corrected!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here are a few quick savings, taking input as a 2D array, to get you down to 68 bytes: https://tio.run/##jU/LboMwELznL0LbyG6oFUhyNOp/sNQY6oAjs6a226pS/p0acujjFEuzO2vNzGrP8kP61ukxPKF9VZPglhcnYtkgR6J5oZkfjQ41YE0pO1uNM12d@BR1V5XkhVwIaVJDeeFKU/FmS@Z@udQ1Zd7oVpGGGYVd6ClNHS8rutm4qbXorVHM2I4IUiYyPsD/NUmTpgG8Ig5tUlG6@u39O81JWb4/HAGPh32eRctuB/iD5SOLLFtKfkOeHwCtBRwcoFKAYQ3YC0AdgRGdiKHr57v7hxfAzSOhYgv49qlc@AJ813aUPgpCr330eBEvC8qHefH0DQ

Comment: @Shaggy - Nice, however I don't get the purpose of `&&r` at end?

Comment: @KévinBibollet, it's needed in order to return the final result of `r`. Without it, the result of the mapping would be returned instead.

Comment: If you *want* to retain the I/O format used in the test cases, though, you can still get down to [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##jU/LboMwELznL0JbZCfUCiQ5GvU/WGoMtcCRWRPbbVUp/04NPfRx6koz@9DOrPYi36TvnJ7CI9oXNQs@W15aNsqJSF5K5iejQ7Np1glpM0N56SpT83ZPlny7NQ1l3uhOkZYZhX0YKM0cr2qapo5drMYonzuL3hrFjO2JIFUiYwD@5SRL2hbwC7HpkprSzU/t725xyovj6Qx4Ph2LPEoOB8BvrIM8VvlKxT/8/AhoLeDoAJUCDFvAQQDqCIzoRTTdPt3dPzwDpjtCxR7w@q5c@AB81XaSPi6EQfuo8SJ@FpQPy@H5Ew) but you should note that I/O is flexible.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
L.tb0VyQsme #dy #N
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=L.tb0VyQsme+%23dy+%23N&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B%2212345%22%2C%2254321%22%5D%2C%5B%2200%22%2C%2200%22%2C%2200%22%2C%2200%22%5D%2C%5B%22001%22%2C%22011%22%2C%22012%22%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%22aaaa%22%2C%22aaaa%22%2C%22aaaa%22%2C%22aaaa%22%5D%2C%5B%22bb%22%2C%22bb%22%2C%22bb%22%5D%2C%5B%22c%22%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%27sm%27%2C+%27oo%27%2C+%27mr%27%2C+%27ee%27%2C+%27t%21%27%2C+%27h_%27%2C+%27i_%27%2C+%27n_%27%2C+%27g_%27%5D%2C+%5B%27%21%40%23%24%25%5E%27%2C+%27%26%2a%28%29_%2B%27%2C+%27qwerty%27%2C+%27uiopas%27%5D%2C+%5B%27this%27%2C+%27is+a%27%2C+%27test%27%5D%5D&debug=0) (note: the code itself evaluates only one block, the interpreter's test suite mode runs the program once for each line of input)

Based on [TFeld's Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186373/71803).

Explanation:

```py
L.tb0         # define a lambda function called y which does a transpose, padding with integer 0's
VyQ           # loop over transposed first input line (Q = eval(input()) ) (loop index = N)
   s          # concatenate array of strings (implicitly printed)
    m         # map over
         y #N # transpose of non-falsy values of N
     e        # for each item: last element of array
       #d     # relevant space at the start! filter with identity function, removes falsy values
```

for an explanation of why the algorithm itself works, see TFeld's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Tutorial), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
ＦθＰι
```

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##DYw7DsIwEAV7TpGYj2w@J6BJhWjo6LLBsiILr@SsE3sD4vRmi2me5s0YXB6Ti7XeUtaL2TTNY42Mc0ZijeZaa9@rMgGlBDRlIO@BuAUKFggFEt5WnVXbbXf7F9DhqI09AS1fn/kHtGKaXRGBAxb5FOuk4AvL9Ly3ahjq5RP/) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXndrzfs@Hczv//o6OVinNj8vLzY/Jyi2LyUlNj8koUY/Iy4mPyMoE4D4jT45V0lBQdlFVU42Ly1LQ0NOO1Y/IKy1OLSipj8koz8wsSi4EKSjIyi4F6iuMTgSakFpcAhUI8FJViYwE).

**Explanation:**

Loop over the input-list of multi-line strings:

```
For(q)
Ｆθ
```

And print the multi-line string without moving the cursor:

```
Multiprint(i);
Ｐι
```